# Difference between "OfAllElements" and "OfElement" for ExpectedConditions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriverwait

For example, [Docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) say

> **presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)**
>
> An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page.

and

> **presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)**
>
> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page.

But honestly, these definitions sounds equivalent to me. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question, correct me if I'm wrong:

> **presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)**
>
> Checks that all the elements located using the locater are present.
>
> **presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)**
>
> Checks that the first element located using the locator is present.